# How to optimize the process doing loop over Pandas DataFrame for big datasets?

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx

I would like to move from the dataset, like this

```
           AAPL  GOOGL   FB   PG
AAPL         50      5    6   30
GOOGL       120     10   12   30
  FB          5      6    1    4
  PG         30     30    4   40
```

to the list of edges, if the values in the matrix satisfy some particular conditions

But my dataset is quite big with a matrix approx. 3500x3500. So the code becomes super memory-consuming.

```
r = [[50, 5, 6, 0],[120, 10, 12, 30],[5, 6, 1, 4],[0, 30, 4, 40]]
ind = ['AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'FB', 'PG']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=ind)
df1.index = ind
G = nx.Graph()
l = list(df1)
for item_v in l:
    for item_h in l:
        if (l.index(item_v) < l.index(item_h)) and (1 - cosine(df1[item_v], df1[item_h]) > 0.01):
            G.add_edge(item_h, item_v)
```

Maybe it can be a bit more efficient?(e.g. if I calculate cosine manually etc.)

Comment: [This article](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) seems relevant.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot!